# UIWebView issue while loading locally stored mp3 audio file

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiwebview

I have a a mp3 file stored locally in documents directory. I get the path for the file correctly. I generate a file URL from the path. I create request to load the audio like so

```
self.iWebView?.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
self.iWebView?.scalesPageToFit = false
let mediaURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: aURL.path)
self.iWebView?.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: mediaURL))
```

The problem is the controls to play the audio file within the UIWebView are misplaced as in the image below. How can I solve this problem?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Please try this

```
let myHTMLString = String(format: "<div style='clear: both;'></div><div style='width: 570px; height: 100px; padding-top: 25px; overflow: hidden;'><audio controls> <source src=\"file:%@\"></audio></div>", filePath)
 self.iWebView?.loadHTMLString(myHTMLString, baseURL: nil)
```

> filePath is file of local mp3 file

Comment: this is not applicable in my case.

Comment: is this necessary to play this file into Webview ???or ve can play it in audio player as well

Comment: I had earlier planned for a custom audio player but it would be an overkill considering the project. Plus we have this requirement of using Webview forced on us

Comment: will try this out

Comment: it gives me a control with play button, which displays the string "Error" besides the play button when played

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144540/discussion-between-matloob-hasnain-and-rohan-bhale).